# Performance of Fused vs Non Fused convolutions during inference

Tags: tensorflow.js

My Network is currently running quite slowly on tfjs and, while trying to understand why other larger models (in size) run faster, I saw that other networks use fused layers.

Does anyone knows what would be the performance difference in speed using FusedConvolutions vs non Fused ones in tfjs during inference?

Thanks